# What is the best way to manage handoff between two Wi-Fi client devices on one laptop?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wifi-configuration

I have an 802.11ac router, my laptop has an internal card that only supports 2.4GHz, and the laptop also has a very small USB adapter that only supports 5GHz.

I constantly have issues with the handoff between these two devices.

For example, if I move across my house, my 2.4GHz band has better reception but my computer won't make the jump.

Similarly, when I get to work I need my device on 5GHz but if the laptop was put to sleep while on the 2.4GHz, when I awake it continues to "not find" a 2.4GHz device.

Windows 8.1 laptop.

Is there a good piece of software or other device that can enable the handoff between these two devices more intelligently?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution to this would be to upgrade to a decent dual-band USB Wi-Fi dongle and disable your laptop's old 2.4GHz-only radio.